# Dimensions of matrix-ndarray multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering what the best way is to write code that can deal with sparse and dense matrices. The following example shows my concern:

input:

```
A = np.asmatrix(np.ones((2,3)))
B = sps.csr_matrix(A)
x = np.ones(3)
print(A.dot(x).shape, B.dot(x).shape)
```

output:

```
(1, 2) (2,)
```

The first result seems wrong from a mathematical perspective. Feeding the result to a function that expects a vector gives an error. I could cast the output into an array and squeeze it:

```
print(np.asarray(A.dot(x)).squeeze().shape)
(2,)
```

Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### dense

```
In [135]: A.dot(x)
Out[135]: matrix([[3., 3.]])
In [136]: np.ones((2,3)).dot(x)
Out[136]: array([3., 3.])
```

`np.matrix` is a subclass of `ndarray` that must be 2d, and tries, as much as possible, to return `np.matrix` (2d) results.  Hence `Out[135]` is 2d (1,2).

`Out[136]` on the other hand is a (2,3) dot (3,) => (2,).  But it is worth keeping mind that `dot` has some special rules when one or other of the inputs is 1d.

Pure `np.matrix` dot:

```
In [161]: A.dot(np.matrix(x).T)   # A*np.matrix(x).T
Out[161]: 
matrix([[3.],
        [3.]])
```

### sparse

While `sparse` matrix is modeled on `np.matrix`, it is its own class, and behaves differently in many cases.  `dot` of sparse and dense can be tricky.

```
In [152]: B.shape
Out[152]: (2, 3)
In [153]: B.dot(x)
Out[153]: array([3., 3.])
```

Effectively the `B` has been turned into an array first:

```
In [154]: B.A.dot(x)         # B.toarray()
Out[154]: array([3., 3.])
```

But this is wrong, because it attempts to use `np.array(B)` instead of the proper `B.toarray()`:

```
In [155]: np.dot(B,x)
Out[155]: 
array([<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
In [156]: np.array(B)
Out[156]: 
array(<2x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

If both variables are sparse, then the result is also sparse.  In this case the special `dot` handling of 1d arrays does not apply.  A (2,3) has to multiply a (3,1), producing a (2,1):

```
In [158]: B*sparse.csr_matrix(x).T
Out[158]: 
<2x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 2 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [159]: _.A
Out[159]: 
array([[3.],
       [3.]])
```

In sum, mixing matrix types can be confusing.  It would be cleanest to convert everything to `ndarray` first.  But it really depends on what kind of output you want.

Comment: Thank you. About dense: why does it not return a 2d result of dimensions (2,1)?

Comment: Evidently it is doing the array dot, and then converting the result to `np.matrix`.  If instead it converted `x` to `np.matrix` first it would give a dimension error.